# How to remove the <p></p> surrounding every table cell rendered by Plastex?

Tags: tex4ht, latex2html

Plastex renders beautiful HTML from LaTeX... to a point. 
One problem is that the content of every cell in tables is surrounded by HTML tags

```
p> content </p
```

even though it is already inside a

```
td > </td
```

like this

```
<td ><p> content </p></td>
```

That adds a lot of padding above and below "content" that makes tables look awful.

A similar thing happens for the Bibliography.

Does anyone know what to modify in Plastex's python code, ccs style sheets, etc. to prevent it from adding the unnecessary p tags?

=== MWE ===

LaTeX

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
content & content\\\hline
content & content\\\hline
content & content\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Plastex output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div> <table cellspacing="0" class="tabular">
<tr>

<td style="border-top-style:solid; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top-color:black; border-top-width:1px; text-align:center"><p>content </p></td>

<td style="border-top-style:solid; text-align:center; border-top-color:black; border-top-width:1px; border-right:1px solid black"><p> content</p>    </td>

</tr><tr>

<td style="border-top-style:solid; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top-color:black; border-top-width:1px; text-align:center"><p>content </p></td>

<td style="border-top-style:solid; text-align:center; border-top-color:black; border-top-width:1px; border-right:1px solid black"><p> content</p></td>

</tr><tr>

<td style="border-top-style:solid; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top-color:black; border-top-width:1px; border-bottom-color:black; text-align:center"><p>content </p></td>

<td style="border-top-style:solid; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top-color:black; border-top-width:1px; text-align:center"><p> content</p></td>

</tr>
</table> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you display the HTML in a browser, you will see the cells of the table have 3 lines each, so they are thick. Instead, if you run the LaTeX code through LaTeX, the cells are 1-line each and the table is compact, as it should.

The problem is that Plastex encloses the content of each cell with an HTML p tag, even though the content is already inside a td tag. the p tag is redundant.

Plastex code source is Python and available, but it is extensive and I do not know where to look.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can we get a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: What about post-processing? (I suggest this because I have never tried working with PlasTeX.)

Comment: post-processing, as a last resort sure, but I have 37 tables spread over a 450 page book, so I'd rather modify Plastex's python code, which I have to learn anyway. I just need some guidance to get started. thanks.

Comment: Rendering is done in Bibliography.zpts using this code `name: thebibliography
type: xml
<dl class="bibliography">
<metal:block tal:repeat="item self">
<dt>
[<a tal:attributes="name item/id" tal:content="item/bibcite"></a>]
</dt>
<dd tal:content="item">information</dd>
</metal:block>
</dl>
` where you can see the `<p></p>` is not there but it must come already embedded inside "`item`", but I do not understand where `"item"` is built ???

Answer (score 1):

I owe everything I know about Plastex to Tim Arnold and Kevin Smith. Without them I am clueless. Echeban.

Following Kevin's (less preferred) recommendation I set forceParse false in class bibitem:

```
class bibitem(List.item):
    args = '[ label ] key:str'
    # Echeban
    forcePars = False
    # End Echeban
```

forceParse = True -> forces <p> markup on the set of child nodes of a node. I layman's language this means for example that once all of the content of an \item is collected, it is enclosed in a <p> tag. This is done to preserve the paragraphs of the original \item. But a \bibitem is always a single paragraph, and enclosing it in <p> added a space before and after each \bibitem, which does not look right, especially on ePub. So, I decided to take that space out by setting forceParse = False which has the effect of not adding the <p> tag. It works!

Now I have to remove the <p> from the cell content of tables. Otherwise the tables spread out a lot and don't look good like on paper.

Comment: Even after removing the extra blank line produced by the <p></p> the Bibliography looks ugly because it is set up with <dl></dl> which puts a line for the citation number like `[1]` and types the actual citation on a separate line. Ugly. The solution is easy. Render the citation in the .zpts file using <li></li>, as follows: `<ol class="bibliography">
<metal:block tal:repeat="item self">
<li tal:content="item">information</li>
</metal:block>
</ol>
`

Comment: forcePars=False did not work for Tables, but I found a better answer: just use a css style sheet to make the p tag invisible inside a table or tabular environment                                                                           `div.table p {
 margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em;
}

div.tabular p {
 margin-top: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em;
}
` :)